# Dynamic Fomuna POI

Tags: apache-poi

I have two values, a fixed one, but a dynamic one in a cell, that once the excel has been created, the user must be able to modify it, and according to this modification, a formula will refresh another cell.

```
Double ausencias = 4.0;

Cell cellDesgloseCalendario = rowDesglose.createCell(cellnum++);
cellDesgloseCalendario.setCellValue(160.0);//value that the user should be able to change later

////
String strFormula= "=ausencias/cellDesgloseCalendario";
cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
cell.setCellFormula(strFormula);
Cell cellDesglosePorcentajeAbsentismo = rowDesglose.createCell(cellnum++);
cellDesglosePorcentajeAbsentismo.setCellFormula(strFormula);
```

How can I dynamically take the position of the column: "cellDesgloseCalendario" (e: "A10", "B20"), since they are created with several loops and I do not know their position, to create the formula that is the division of this column by my variable "ausencias"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cell knows it's address. One can get it via [Cell.getAddress](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getAddress--). So one can concatenating the address into a formula string.

But you must not start a formula string with "=" in `apache poi` since this is not expected. See [Formula Support - basics](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/formula.html#The+basics).

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class CreateExcelFormulaUsingCellAddress {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
  Row rowDesglose = sheet.createRow(0);

  Double ausencias = 4.0;

  int cellnum = 0;

  Cell cellDesgloseCalendario = rowDesglose.createCell(cellnum++); // cellDesgloseCalendario is A1
  cellDesgloseCalendario.setCellValue(160.0);

  String strFormula = ausencias.toString() + "/" + cellDesgloseCalendario.getAddress().formatAsString();
                   // 4.0                     /    A1
System.out.println(strFormula); //"4.0/A1"

  Cell cellDesglosePorcentajeAbsentismo = rowDesglose.createCell(cellnum++); // cellDesglosePorcentajeAbsentismo is B1
  cellDesglosePorcentajeAbsentismo.setCellFormula(strFormula); //formula in B1 is now =4/A1

  wb.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelFormulaUsingCellAddress.xlsx"));
  wb.close();
 }

}
```